# Technology selection for "Right sequence finder for QWOP game" -tool

Tags: flash, user-interface, artificial-intelligence

I would like to code an script that would with some trial and error method learn to play QWOP game, that is available at Flash format on Internet ([more information on QWOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWOP)). I found out there are some challenges on it:

- The program is available on Flash and I don't know how any Script (I am planning to use JavaScript) could use virtually its UI, it means to send the appropriate key strokes to the game UI.
- I know Java Script is not the easiest language to master and especially there are challenges on such a complicated coding aim as Artificial Intelligence.

**My question is what would be the best tool or language with which I could make this quite funny experiment in practice?**

**For those who don't know, QWOP is a game, where a character is supposed to run a 100m run with manual instructions for leg movements given with keys Q, W, O and P.*

***The game is stated to be very hard to master with normal human intelligence, and thus it seems to be ideal for some artificial intelligence testing. Similarly interesting than inventing an AI chess player towards human intelligence.*

Comment: Sidenote: I don't want answers on playing the game itself but only for a language or tool for creating an AI to make it.

Comment: There is no good tool for it and you are not going to get any kind of reasonable performance by trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, even assuming your bot works at a slow 2Hz frequency, it will have to make 4<sup>2t</sup> choices in a game lasting *t* seconds. If you want to learn just the first 5 seconds of the game, you will need **2 months** to try all the possibilities.

In terms of implementation, the best way to go would probably be to reverse the game and make your own Flash app that would cycle combinations using the same algorithm. This way, you don't have to wait for the game to play out in real time and skip all the trouble with input simulation and output detection.

Comment: About the suggested implementation by own flash: what you exactly mean by "would cycle combinations using the same algorithm"?

Comment: I mean that it would be easiest to reverse the game back to ActionScript, take its implemntation of the algorithm, and then build on it to do trial and error. It would be much faster and easier than trying to control the game indirectly. Still totally impractical, though.

Comment: Ok, this was not good case for testing AI. Anyways, I'll accept your answer because knowing that something is impossible or useless is also a good piece of information.